# Codeigniter : unable to parse array

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am fetching data like this from database

```
 function getdiningdata($type){
        $rest[$type]= $this->db->get_where('dining',array(
            'type'=> $type,
        ))->result();
         foreach ($rest[$type] as $value){

            $value->images  = $this->db->get_where('diningattachments',array(
                    'diningid'  => $value->id
                )
            )->result();
        }
    }
```

in second function i am getting data like this

```
function dinewithus(){

    $data['sensi']= $this->getdiningdata('sensi');
    $this->load->view('front/dine',$data);

 }

Array
(
    [sensi] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [title] => SENSI
                    [text] => data
                    [type] => sensi
                    [images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 1
                                    [diningid] => 1
                                    [image] => sensi3.jpg
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 2
                                    [diningid] => 1
                                    [image] => sensi_last.JPG
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i am trying to access $sensi in my view but thats not working . Please help me how can i parse the data in my view . Thanks

Comment: getdiningdata() doesn't return anything for $data

Comment: oh my god .....

Comment: return data from your model

Answer (score 0):

Hi sikandar you are sending data, variable named `sensi` on view page.

```
$data['sensi']= $this->getdiningdata('sensi');
$this->load->view('front/dine',$data);
```

on the view page you should get this array like : As I think,

```
print_r($sensi->sensi);
```

because variable name is `$sensi` and array first element name is also `sensi`